# Limit gives wrong answer on both Mathematica 12.0 and Wolfram-Alpha

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-12.0

[image: My input and output]

```
Limit[(Cos[x^2]/(x^2) - Cos[(x + 1)^2]/((x + 1)^2))/(1/(x^3)), x -> Infinity]

Plot[(Cos[x^2]/(x^2) - Cos[(x + 1)^2]/((x + 1)^2))/(1/(x^3)), {x, 0, 1000}]
```

The two results in this image are contradictory.

Clearly,the answer of the limit is not correct.

It seems that my problem may not appear on someone else's computer.My version is 12.0.0.0,and according to the comments,there is no problem on version 12.2

However,what astonished me most is that Wolfram-Alpha gives the same wrong answer without providing step-by-step solution.

[image: The result on Wolfram-Alpha]

What's wrong with this?Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please present the Matematica codes in a copyable form.

Comment: Can't reproduce it in 12.2: the limit is returned unevalued.

Comment: My version is 12.0.0.0

Comment: Some things change to better.

Comment: Confirm wrong result `0` in W|A.

Comment: I have replaced the picture with a more complete one

Comment: In 12.1 the limit returns unevaluated